# dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu, windows wont boot

Tags: dual-boot

lets start this off with some info, i had windows 10 installed first then i dual booted with Ubuntu. later i decided i didn't really like the version of Ubuntu i had install. following some procedures to delete the partition i had made but it would not allow me to merge it back so i gave it a reboot. i know other people have asked this same question but none of the answers that were given helped me. anyways after i attempted to restart my pc back into windows, it gave me a error and grub rescue i followed what was said to fix the problem yet nothing, i have looked on multiple websites. people have been saying use the .iso image to repair windows but i only have one usb and it has Ubuntu on it. i am able to boot into Ubuntu but not back into windows, i try to boot into windows and it takes me to grub rescue. is there anyway to have the iso on the same usb and repair it that way?
any help is much appreciated!

Comment: There are only 2 answers, onde ir them will certainly help you: If BIOS/Legacy you need to boot from Windows installation or recovery media and recover MBR (specific instructions are off-topic gere, obviously); If UEFI all you need to do is change the boot order at UEFI settings.

Answer (score 0):

I guess reinstalling Ubuntu helped it also replaced the boot loader. I tried using the boot loader fixer from the website and it didn't help any. I believe something went wrong when I first installed Ubuntu but anyways!